# ContentVeil.js and Forced Synchronous Layout Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a php page that hangs for 3-10 seconds after the page loads, you can't even scroll up or down, or close the tab when this happens. (the chrome loading gif still loops tho) Happens in Chrome and IE.

Chrome Timeline: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxuAl.png

Shows ContentVeil.js repeating over and over. I think it is client side(?), I did a grepWIN to search for ContentVeil, with no luck, and it doesn't show up in Chrome Network tab.

Chrome Profile: Second image, from above link.

I think this shows the issue at the anonymous function from meta-boxes.min.js, ln 1.

meta-boxes.min.js: http://pastebin.com/yqtJyqB1

Unfortunately line one is a function that encapsulates the whole script. I don't know js very well, I tried to just remove each function one by one but that just created more errors.

Any ideas on how I could find the source of the problem would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It's part of the Evernote web clipping extension, and it's hooks DOM events, causing massive slowdowns if you are doing large amount of dom changes.